# How can i find the latest partition in impala tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I need to collect the incremental stats frequently on a table, for that, i need to populate the latest partitions for the below variable:

```
compute incremental stats someSchema.someTable partition (partitionColName=${value});
```

I have few options with me which I don't want to use for stability and performance concerns, below are the options that I have using the shell script:

```
TabMaxPartDt=$(impala-shell --ssl -k -i ${ConnString} -B -q "select max(PartitionColName) from someSchema.someTableName")

#Collecting the stats using the variable TabMaxPartDt

compute incremental stats someSchema.someTable partition (partitionColName=${TabMaxPartDt});

#Other dirty and easiest option is to predict the date with the current date as I'm doing the partition with current date

dt=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

compute incremental stats someSchema.someTable partition (partitionColName=${dt});
```

I want to find out if there any option in impala to get the latest partition without running the memory consuming query? and without guessing the partition?

I tried to find in impala doc if there is something like `show latest partition tableName;` as `show partitions tableName` but no luck on that.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Suggestion: Query the Hive MetaStore directly

Comment: How can I do that ? If you can add any doc that will be great.

Comment: I think this is something i can do latestPart=$(hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=false; show partitions schema.tableName;' | tail -1 | cut -d'=' -f2)

Comment: I assume you're using CDH, with cloudera manager, or at least have access to read the hive site XML?  The metastore is configured there, and is either a Mysql or Postgres database that you need to know the password for.... Otherwise, your only option is to use `SHOW PARTITIONS`, dump it into a file, then `tail` the file

Comment: Right, except remove the cut since there's not always one partition